# Magento - Ajax Request - Returns empty response

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I am debugging some stuff on a client's site that has a module developed by someone else. It's not working correctly.

I have a simple Ajax call to a controller:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : "http://www.site.com/quickview/index/cart",
    complete : function(data){
                    // data.responseText is empty here.
                    jQuery('span.topLinks').replaceWith(data.responseText);
                    // This returns the data object with statusText = "error"
                    console.log(data);
    }
})
```

Which calls a simple action in the controller:

```
    public function cartAction()
    {
        // This log call never fires
        Mage::log('foobar',null,'temp.log');
        $this->loadLayout();
        $Top = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($Top);
    }
```

The problem is that the  Ajax call never makes it to the controller. I have placed a Mage::log call inside the cartAction(), but it never gets fired.

The controller is indeed set up properly, as I can browse directly to cartAction() which will render the block I am attempting to return back to the Ajax call (if I echo it, it's not echoed here).

If I place inside the Ajax call:

```
console.log(data);
```

It returns the object with  statusText: "error".

I have tried every permutation of the Ajax URL that I can think of, absolute, relative, with index.php, without index.php, etc. Every time, data.responseText is just an empty string.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe your module's frontname is `quickview`, controller is `IndexController` and method name is `cartAction`. If all is right and you have jquery firing ajax, then it should be called.

Comment: where do you placed `Mage::log`? I believe just after starting curly brace of `cartAction()`.

Comment: yes, Mage::log anywhere inside the cartAction() method.

Comment: not anywhere, just after start of function.

Comment: can you post the `request`, that is fired through ajax?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I have posted all the relevant details. I will modify the question to be more clear.

Comment: ok. can you see the ajax been fired? through firebug? I want that data to be posted here

Comment: Are you sure that magento has the rights to create the temp.log file? If not, you don't get a log entry.

Comment: The temp.log file gets created if I access the controller action directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was finally resolved. The module also had a controller set up for Adminhtml that used the same frontname so browsing to the controller action directly worked, but when called through the template file via Ajax, it didn't like the http to https switch.

Assigned a different frontname to the admin controller and things are fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try changing the URL to a standard Magento URL and check if you get a response. At least you would know if the problem is coming from your jQuery request or your controller itself. If you can access your controller action directly in your browser, your module is just fine.

Comment: Yes, the controller action is accessed directly in the browser without problems. I have since discovered, however, that the same code works without problem on a dev site that was set up, so this appears to be some kind of server config issue.